# Splitting a string to do some math yields strange result, in Python

Tags: python, string, math, split

So I'll admit that this is a homework assignment, but I'm not asking you all to do it for me, I'm just looking for some guidance. We need to make a Python program to accept a time in Hours:Minutes (2:30) format in a single string, and output the amount of time in minutes. (i.e. 2 hours and 30 minutes = 150 minutes)

I still need to work out some limitations for the string input:

1. Make sure it only uses digits and a colon
2. Make sure it can only accept five characters (##:##)
3. Make sure that the middle character is a colon (i.e. numbers are in correct order)
4. and make sure that if a time like 4:35 was entered, that a zero would be added in front automatically

I'll work on that later — for now I decided to work on the math I would get from the input.

It made sense to me to slice the string into two parts: hours and minutes. I then multiplied the amount of hours by 60 and added them to the pre-existing minutes to get a total amount of minutes. However, right now, entering a time like 02:45 is outputting a minute amount of 02020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020245.

Any idea what might be going wrong here? Just to be clear, this is homework and I want to work out the input limitations on my own, I just need help moving past this math issue.

```
#Henry Quinn - Python Advanced 4.0 Hours and Minutes
import re
print "This program takes an input of time in hours and minutes and outputs the amount    of minutes."
count = 0

#I still need to work out while loop
#Supposed to make sure that a time is entered correctly, or error out
while (count <1):
    time = raw_input("Please enter the duration of time (ex: 2:15 or 12:30): ")
    if not re.match("^[0-9, :]*$", time):
        print "Sorry, you're only allowed to use the numbers 0-9."
    elif len(time) > 5:
        print "Sorry, only five characters max allowed."
#MAKE THIS CHECK FOR A COLON
#elif
#elif
    else:
        count = count + 1

#If time = 12:45, hours should be equal to 12, and minutes should be equal to 45
hours = time[:2]
minutes = time[3:]

#Should convert hours to minutes
newhours = hours * 60

#Should make total amount of minutes
totalminutes = newhours + minutes

print "The total amount of elapsed minutes is %s" % (totalminutes)

raw_input("Please press Enter to terminate the program.")
```

Comment: multiplying a string * an integer makes a string with lots of copies of the original string. Call `int()` on the numeric string first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, hours and minutes are string variables, not ints. Thus, you can't multiply them as you would a number.

Change lines 20 and 21 to

```
hours = int(time[:2])
minutes = int(time[3:])
```

And putting in 02:45 should work. However, you will still run into problems if you don't have that leading 0 (like if you put in 2:45), so might I suggest you instead split it around the ":", like so:

```
hours = int(time.split(":")[0])
minutes = int(time.split(":")[1])
```

Comment: `hours, minutes = map(int, time.split(':'))`

Comment: Yeah, I was worried about leaving out the leading digit on the time input. Let me try this out and get back to you.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Absolutely, I was just keeping the syntax simple since I knew he's new to Python

Comment: @DavidRobinson:  I agree you took the best approach.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, would that split the string at the colon?

Comment: @HenryEdwardQuinnIV: Yes it would (it would do the same thing my code does)

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. The program works. This is my first post; what's the protocol on showing everyone the fixed and working code?

Answer (score 3):

You are multiplying a string with integer.

```
>>> st = '20'
>>> st*3
'202020'
>>> int(st)*3
60
>>>
```

Type cast it to `int`.

So, change this

```
minutes = time[3:]
newhours = hours * 60
```

to

```
 minutes = int(time[3:])
 newhours = int(hours) * 60
```

Comment: Someone else told me this as well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, here's an solution - if you figure out how it works, I guarantee you learn something new ;)

```
tre = re.compile("([0-2]?[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])")
h,m = ((int(_) for _ in tre.match("2:30").groups())
td = timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m)
print(td.total_seconds() / 60)
```

Comment: I've gotten the answer I need, but I'm going to try and figure your post out so I can impress my professor. I just want it to be known I have no idea what regular expressions are; just happened to stumble onto them while Google-ing. Currently learning my first language.

Comment: I'm not sure what compiling it actually does, but it seems to limit each digit in the time to be between a certain range of numbers. You gave me 0-2 for the first digit though, so it seems that this could be used for military time, as well. Does the tre.match then split up the string using the colon as the median?

Comment: The magic thing in the regexp are the parentheses `()` - they create _group_s - so in practice it does the same thing as splitting the string using semicolon as the separator.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd and 4th requirements contradict each other. Either you accept only 5 characters strings or you allow also `#:##` (4 characters form).

```
import re

def minutes(timestr):
    """Return number of minutes in timestr that must be either ##:## or #:##."""
    m = re.match(r"(\d?\d):(\d\d)$", timestr)
    if m is None:
       raise ValueError("Invalid timestr: %r" % (timestr,))
    h, m = map(int, m.groups())
    return 60*h + m
```

If you allow spaces inside the `timestr` and `##:#`, `#:#`, etc forms then:

```
def minutes2(timestr):
    h, m = map(int, timestr.partition(':')[::2])
    return 60*h + m
```

If you'd like to restrict hours to 0..23 and minutes to 0..59 then:

```
import time

def minutes3(timestr):
    t = time.strptime(timestr, "%H:%M")
    return 60*t.tm_hour + t.tm_min
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/tC9Bb)

```
minutes ('12:11') -> 731
minutes2('12:11') -> 731
minutes3('12:11') -> 731
minutes ('  12:11') -> error: Invalid timestr: '  12:11'
minutes2('  12:11') -> 731
minutes3('  12:11') -> error: time data '  12:11' does not match format '%H:%M'
minutes ('12:11  ') -> error: Invalid timestr: '12:11  '
minutes2('12:11  ') -> 731
minutes3('12:11  ') -> error: unconverted data remains:   
minutes ('3:45') -> 225
minutes2('3:45') -> 225
minutes3('3:45') -> 225
minutes ('03:45') -> 225
minutes2('03:45') -> 225
minutes3('03:45') -> 225
minutes ('13:4') -> error: Invalid timestr: '13:4'
minutes2('13:4') -> 784
minutes3('13:4') -> 784
minutes ('13:04') -> 784
minutes2('13:04') -> 784
minutes3('13:04') -> 784
minutes ('24:00') -> 1440
minutes2('24:00') -> 1440
minutes3('24:00') -> error: time data '24:00' does not match format '%H:%M'
minutes ('11:60') -> 720
minutes2('11:60') -> 720
minutes3('11:60') -> error: unconverted data remains: 0
```

Comment: I got my program working with another answer. Could you go into a bit more detail on how to implement minutes2 into my existing code?

Comment: `minutes2` is a function. Call it to get the result: `minutes2('12:11')` or in your case `totalminutes = minutes2(time)`. Your specific issue (`"1"*2` vs. `1*2`) is covered in other answers. My answer demonstrates that the requirements you were given are contradictory ('##:##' vs. '#:##') and incomplete (allowed range for hours, minutes is not specified). Each function `minutes()` follows slightly different set of requirements.